# AWSにおけるパブリックDNSという概念について

Tags: aws

EC2インスタンスでパブリックDNSというものがあります、
たとえばそれをブラウザのURLで指定すればインターネット上からアプリケーションにアクセスできたり、
ssh先に設定できたり。

ここで疑問です。
パブリックDNSという名前はどう解釈すればいいのでしょうか。
先述の使い方では、ホスト名になっていて、それにアクセスするとインスタンスまでいきつけるという役割になってるかと思いますが、そもそもDNSはホストとIPをマッピングするものです。

パブリックホストならしっくりくるのですが、パブリックDNSとはパブリックにだれてもアクセスできるDNSという意味に解釈できて、今ネーミングに違和感を感じます。

AWSの人しかわからんよ、、とか言われるかもですがわかる方がいればご回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPCのドキュメントで用語の説明がされています。

[VPC での DNS の使用 - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html)

> DNS ホスト名
>
> デフォルト VPC 内にインスタンスを起動すると、パブリック IPv4 アドレスとプライベート IPv4 アドレスに対応するパブリック DNS ホスト名およびプライベート DNS ホスト名がインスタンスに割り当てられます。デフォルト以外の VPC 内にインスタンスを起動すると、プライベート DNS ホスト名がインスタンスに割り当てられ、VPC に指定した DNS 属性に応じて、およびインスタンスにパブリック IPv4 アドレスがある場合、パブリック DNS ホスト名が割り当てられる可能性があります。
>
> Amazon が提供するプライベート (内部) DNS ホスト名はインスタンスのプライベート IPv4 アドレスに解決され、ip-private-ipv4-address.ec2.internal の書式が us-east-1 リージョンに使用され、ip-private-ipv4-address.region.compute.internal の書式が (private.ipv4.address が逆引きルックアップ IP アドレスとなっている) 他のリージョンに使用されます。プライベート DNS ホスト名は、同じネットワーク内のインスタンス間の通信に使用できます。ただし、インスタンスが含まれるネットワークの外部の DNS ホスト名を解決することはできません。
>
> パブリック (外部) DNS ホスト名には、us-east-1 リージョンには ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com 書式、その他のリージョンには ec2-public-ipv4-address.region.amazonaws.com 書式が使用されます。パブリック DNS ホスト名を解決すると、インスタンスのパブリック IPv4 アドレス (インスタンスのネットワークの外部の場合) およびインスタンスのプライベート IPv4 アドレス (インスタンスのネットワーク内からの場合) となります。
>
> IPv6 アドレスの DNS ホスト名は付与されません。

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon EC2 インスタンスの IP アドレッシング](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)には

> - プライベート IPv4 アドレスと内部 DNS ホスト名
> - パブリック IPv4 アドレスと外部 DNS ホスト名

と表現されていて、厳密には「パブリックDNS」という表現はされていません。

コンソールは確かに **パブリック DNS (IPv4)** という表記になっていますが、説明ツールチップには

> インスタンスのパブリックホスト名により、インスタンスのパブリック IP アドレスまたは Elastic IP アドレスが解決されます。

と説明されていて「パブリックDNS」は俗称のように感じました。